# How to Compare an Entire Row to another Row in Excel and Return Value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

[image: Example output]

Is there a formula to do a vLookup, essentially, but instead of comparing one value, you are comparing an entire row to another row to return a value?

I've used =**ISNUMBER**(**MATCH**(B3&C3,B3:B8&C3:C8,0))

=**IF**(**ISNUMBER**(**MATCH**(B3&C3,B3:B8&C3:C8,0)),1,0)

Is there a way to perform this task in excel?  To find duplicate rows and return a match.

[image: Formula Box]

Am I using the =MATCH formula incorrectly?  As you can see from the image, the array that is being returned is correct but the concatenated value is not returning true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps something like the following:

```
=--(COUNTIFS($A$3:A3,A3,$B$3:B3,B3,$C$3:C3,C3)>1)
```

[image]

Comment: What do the 2 dashes do? Still have not figured out the importance of those

Comment: Changes FALSE to 0 and TRUE to 1.